# Selenium Remote WebDriver

Tags: python, linux, selenium, selenium-webdriver

For a project, I need to use Selenium Webdriver for running my test case on a server. I have seen the [documentation](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/getting-started.html#using-selenium-with-remote-webdriver), but I do not know how to implement it in my code and how to use it.

I have already test with:

```
driver = webdriver.Remote(command_executor='http://ip_address:4444/wd/hub/static/resource/hub.html',desired_capabilities=DesiredCapabilities.FIREFOX)
```

But it doesn't work.

PS: I use Python for my test and Linux is the os of my server.

Comment: Your question is too broad. be more specific

Comment: See [mcve]. What exactly does *"it doesn't work"* mean?

Comment: It says : Error : name_file (__main__.name_file)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
driver = webdriver.Remote(command_executor='http://ip_address:4444/wd/hub/',desired_capabilities=DesiredCapabilities.FIREFOX)`
```

the URL you are using in your code there looks quite broken to me :-/

Comment: But it open a window and nothing happend... And after 1min, it says : Stacktrace: at org.openqa...

Comment: Since that one line alone won't do anything but start a selenium session using Firefox, that should be the expected result?

Comment: Normally, it will open the test in the server window, no ?

Comment: If you execute some testing code using the created driver-instance, yes. But you didn't post anything doing that...

Comment: How can I do that ? I'm very bad I think

Comment: Click the link you posted in your description, scroll to the bottom, click "Next ->", the page you find yourself on explains basic stuff. Repeat this pattern until no further "Next ->" is being offered on the page you read.

Comment: Ok thanks, I will look that, and I say you what happend

Comment: We have them too ;) Now you "just" need to implement the tests defined in that protocol as a working Selenium testsuite ;)

Comment: Normally, is already do, because my test protocal is an export of selenium ide, no ?

Comment: What you are trying to do here (code selenium tests in python) and what you have (a selenium IDE export) has as much to do with each other as driving a car and origami.... Maybe it's a car shaped origami...

Comment: Excuse me for my late, my test is just a test, so just open a page, verify something,... and I have a classic code in python from selenium IDE...